# How to assign a list variable to another without linking them?

Tags: python, variables

So, I have a list variable (eg. `var1`) that is assigned to another list variable (eg. `var2`), when `var2` changes `var1` also changes.

**Example:**

```
movement = [3, 0]
projectile_movement = movement
projectile_movement[0] += 1
projectile_movement[1] += 1
```

What I am expecting to happen here, is the original `movement` variable should stay the same, as `projectile_movement` is the one being changed

However, the original `movement` variable is being changed along with `projectile_movement`

How can I stop this from happening?

Comment: `projectile_movement = movement.copy()` - creates a duplicate.

Comment: You will also frequently see `projectile_movement = movement[:]`.  This is a Python idiom that uses slicing to copy an array.

Comment: Your variables are referring *to the same object*. This: `projectile_movement = movement` does not create a new list, it simply says "the name `projectile_movement` now refers to these same object as the object currently being referred to by `movement`.

Comment: Read the following: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html